# Navigate Screen Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have created a basic success screen with Timer control. I want to close the success screen after 5 seconds. The issue I have is the new form display again after closing the success page. What I want is after closing the success page, it shows the SharePoint list. Please see the images for more information.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using `RequestHide()` instead of navigate function. You can also reset form fields using Reset() If you want. Let me Know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
RequestHide()
```

Instead of:

```
Navigate('FormScreen1, Fade)
```

If you want to reset complete form, you can use `ResetForm()` function and use `Reset()` function to reset individual fields as per your requirements.

OR force to open new form next time user opens the same pop up using:

```
NewForm(SharePointForm1)
```